# The name 'fileName' does not exist in the current context - BIML

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, biml

I have a BIML file inspired by [this post](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2017/02/use-biml-and-csv-files-to-create-tables.html) .

However, I am getting an error:

> Error 0   The name 'fileName' does not exist in the current context. (32,16`)

I have the feeling I am missing something really  obvious.
I am running this in `VS 2019 + SSDT` and `BIML Express` (both latest versions as of this moment)
I am talking to

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) 
    Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

This is my BIML code:

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO"#>


<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
 
<#  
    string Prefix="import";
     
    // the locatie of the csv's'
    string path = @"C:\test";
    // Put all the filenames with the extension csv in a string array
    string[] myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.csv");
    // string that will be filled with the filename
    string filename;
    // string array for columnnames extracted from CSV
    string[] myColumns;
#>
        <Connections>
            <OleDbConnection
            Name="OLEDB_STG_<#=Prefix#>" 
            ConnectionString="Data Source=SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=TEST;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;">
            </OleDbConnection>
        </Connections>
        <Databases>
             <Database ConnectionName="OLEDB_STG_<#=Prefix#>" Name="TEST"/>
        </Databases>
       <Schemas>
              <Schema Name="dbo" DatabaseName="TEST" Owner="dbo"/>
       </Schemas>
       <Tables>
            <!-- loop trough the array of files-->
            <#  foreach(string filePath in myFiles) 
                {
               // extract the filename from the path to use as tablename     
               fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
             
            #>
            <Table Name="<#=Prefix#>_<#=fileName#>" SchemaName="TEST.dbo">
                <Columns>
                   <!-- loop trough the file looking for the columnnames-->
                    <#
                    // read first row of csv to extract to columnnames
                    // and split on comma to create an array
                    StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(filePath);
 
                    myColumns = myFile.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    // close file after reading first line
                    myFile.Close();
 
                    // Loop through column array
                    foreach(string myColumn in myColumns) 
                    {  
                    #>
                      <Column Name="<#=myColumn#>" DataType="String" Length="255"></Column>
                 <#  }   #>
                </Columns>    
            </Table>
            <# }#>
       </Tables>
</Biml>
```

Comment: Reading line-by-line and splitting on commas means you will only ever be able to read unquoted CSV files correctly. [RFC4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) allows CSV field data to contain quote, comma and newline characters. Also, C# is a case-sensitive language so `filename` does not refer to the same variable as `fileName`.

Comment: the separator will be a pipe but that is to be made configurable. That should tackle that I believe. The splitting should also occur only on the first line and having columnnames that contain pipes does break some agreements we have in place internally

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Your last comment about case-sensitive was indeed the stupid thing I overlooked! Thanks! Make this into an answer and I"ll credit you with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is a case-sensitive language so `filename` does not refer to the same variable as `fileName`, i.e. these don't match:

```cs
string filename;
fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

As with all XML, BIML IS CASE SENSITIVE.
All Biml objects including the plural collections are case sensitive.

```
// string that will be filled with the filename
    string fileName;
{ // extract the filename from the path to use as tablename     
               fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath); #> }
```